# Keyboard issue with Ctrl button in X11

Tags: x11, keyboard

I've an issue. I think it started several month ago, suspiciously near the update to newest Fedora version. I've used to blame this on hardware, however when I've attached USB keyboard to my laptop (which I've only managed couple of days ago), issues still prevailed, so I think it might be somehow a software issue.

Issue:

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button, nothing happens. E.g., it is not being sent to windows. however, if I chain-press buttons (e.g. ctrl-t, etc), it works. also if I first press Alt, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and then release Alt, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keypress is being sent to the applications.

xev log for the issue:

With only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, only this happens: (doesn't matter left or right ctrl)

https://paste.kde.org/p1rwqrgsr

As you can see, there is NO KeyPress event, nor KeyRelease event.

With Alt-Ctrl-Release Alt sequence, this happens:

https://paste.kde.org/pbqg6vk9s

As you can see, everything is as expected.

What can be the issue behind this? More importantly, what are my options to fix that?

software details: fedora desktop stable latest, gnome flavor. all system configs are default.

Answer (score 1):

The "focus in" and "focus out" events mean some other application is processing the Ctrl key, and only passing on sequences that don't much whatever key combinations it reacts to, That can be your window manager, or one of several programs that allow a foreign language keyboard. Gnome usually uses some *ibus*-application.

The fix is to configure whatever program is processing that event to ignore it, or to uninstall it completely.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I've tried to find an app that might be responsible for that, however nothing in GNOME keyboard manager hotkeys section that might eat up ctrl clicks, nor I didn't find any other background app that could be consuming hotkeys. Suggestions on how to find the culprit?

Comment: Close all applications except a single terminal window, do an `xlsclients`, see if one if those look suspicious.